# How to sort a horizontal bar-chart in descending order with ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I´m trying to create a plot that shows all main categories and their summed up pledged amount in million USD.
Therefore I took a Kickstarter data frame, put the pledged amount *usd_pledged* as x-value and the category *main_category* as the y-value.

To make it more appealing I used `fill = main_category`. After that some labelling took place `labs()`,`theme_classic()`, `theme()`,`guides()` and `scale_x_continous()`

Here is my code:

```
ggplot(Kickstarter, aes(usd_pledged/1000000,                               
                            main_category,                                   
                            fill = main_category)) +                               
  geom_histogram(stat = "identity") +
  labs(x="pledged amount in mio USD", y = "main categories") +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(legend.position="right") +
  guides(fill=guide_legend(title="categories")) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0,0))
```

The result ist:
[basic-plot_Kickstarter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjFl5.png)

Now I´d like to plot this graph in a descending order.
I tried using `reorder()` to get a descending order:

```
ggplot(Kickstarter, aes(usd_pledged/1000000,                               
                            reorder(main_category, +usd_pledged),                                   
                            fill = main_category)) +                               
  geom_histogram(stat = "identity") +
  labs(x="pledged amount in mio USD", y = "main categories") +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(legend.position="right") +
  guides(fill=guide_legend(title="categories")) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0,0))
```

which only kind of sorts it, as the result is:
[halfway sorted plot_Kickstarter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7Zkz.png)

Is there a way to order it correctly? (Games->Design->Technology->Film&Video->Music->Publishing->Food->Fashion->Art->Comics->Theater->Photography->Dance->Journalism->Crafts)

If you need more info, just let me know. This is my first question here :)

head()

```
# A tibble: 6 x 20
          ID name  category main_category currency deadline    goal
       <dbl> <chr> <chr>    <chr>         <chr>    <date>     <dbl>
1 1000003930 Gree~ Narrati~ Film & Video  USD      2017-11-01 30000
2 1000004038 Wher~ Narrati~ Film & Video  USD      2013-02-26 45000
3 1000007540 Tosh~ Music    Music         USD      2012-04-16  5000
4 1000014025 Mona~ Restaur~ Food          USD      2016-04-01 50000
5 1000030581 Chas~ Drinks   Food          USD      2016-03-17 25000
6  100004721 Of J~ Nonfict~ Publishing    CAD      2013-10-09  2500
# ... with 13 more variables: launched <chr>, pledged <dbl>,
#   state <chr>, backers <dbl>, country <chr>, usd_pledged <dbl>,
#   usd_pledged_real <dbl>, usd_goal_real <dbl>, percent <dbl>,
#   launch_year <chr>, runtime <dbl>, state_dv <dbl>, Group <chr>
```

***UPDATE***

After trying out

```
    Kickstarter %>% 
mutate(main_category = fct_reorder(main_category, usd_pledged)) %>% 
ggplot(aes(x=main_category, y=usd_pledged, fill=main_category)) +
      geom_col()+
      coord_flip()
```

it still remains in chaos, as you can see here:
[image]

Comment: A friendly tip about an unrelated point. Color here is redundant. There are two variables in the plot: category and pledge. Each category has its own bar, pledge is represented by bar length. Each bar doesn't need its own color, too. Color adds nothing. Taking out the fill and the legend removes no meaning from the plot. It's better. Color isn't for making a plot "pretty." It should be an aesthetic applied to a variable; like color could map to region and each category could be stacked region bars. Here, the redundancy is even obvious in the code. `main_category` is mapped to two aesthetics.

Answer (score 3):

**Update:** I added some fake values for `usd_pledged` since the column is not reconstructible:

```
library(forcats)  
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
  

df %>% 
  mutate(main_category = fct_reorder(main_category, usd_pledged)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=main_category, y=usd_pledged, fill=main_category)) +
  geom_col()+
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

First answer:
I am not sure but I think you need `geom_col` or `geom_bar`
Here is an example with the mtcars dataset:

1. prepare `mtcars` to get `cars` column and `mpg`
2. use `fct_reorder` from forcats to order `cars` by `mpg`
3. use ggplot with `geom_col`
4. finally `coord_flip()`

```
library(forcats)  
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
  
mtcars %>% 
  rownames_to_column("cars") %>% 
  select(cars, mpg) %>% 
  mutate(cars = fct_reorder(cars, mpg)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(cars, mpg, fill=cars)) +
  geom_col()+
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you TarJae. I tried your idea like this                                               library(forcats)  
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

Kickstarter %>%
  select(main_category, usd_pledged) %>%
  mutate(main_category = fct_reorder(main_category, usd_pledged)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(main_category, usd_pledged, fill=main_category))+
  geom_col()+
  coord_flip()  ################ unfortunately it doesn´t order my plot at all. Did I misunderstand your code? (I honestly don´t know what the second line is for, sorry.)

Comment: Please provide the head of your data. You could do this: `dput(head(Kickstarter))` copy the output and add to your question with edit.

Comment: Please see my update. Now it should work.

Comment: @TarJae, if you give us some data we can help you out. But you have to use `dput`. Just copy/pasting the head() of your data isn't helpful. Please use. `dput(head(Kickstarter))`

Comment: @John J. Thank you very much. But it is not me who is asking this question. Mine should be the answer!

Comment: Sorry, @TarJae! I misread the comment flow. @Shorty, Please provide sample data via `dput`. We need that to replicate your issue.