# Order plot in descending/ascending order doesn't work

Tags: r, ggplot2

We are plotting Data for a Thesis paper and have following code. We want to order the main categories in descending order based on their combined pledged amount.

```
ggplot(Kickstarter, aes(usd_pledged/1000000,                             
                            reorder(main_category,+usd_pledged),                                    
                            fill = main_category))+                               
  geom_col(stat = "identity")+
  labs(x="pledged amount in mio USD", y = "main categories")+
  theme_classic()+
  theme(legend.position="right")+
  guides(fill=guide_legend(title="         categories", ncol = 2))+
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0,0))
```

We have tried different methods as you can see, but they never work completely. This is the current plot created with above code.

[image]

Is there a problem with our code or could there be happening something wired with our Data?
[Used Data](https://www.kaggle.com/kemical/kickstarter-projects?select=ks-projects-201801.csv)

Comment: Try with `reorder(main_category, usd_pledged, FUN = sum, na.rm = TRUE)`. As you have multiple obs per category `reorder` will by default order based on the mean.

Comment: I have a deja vu. You already asked this question? or was it someone else?

Comment: Ok it was someone else with the same question. See here <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70816104/how-to-sort-a-horizontal-bar-chart-in-descending-order-with-ggplot/70816240#70816240>

Comment: I think my colleague already asked this question and didn't tell me. But if you read his comments, the given answer didn't work either. Thank you @stefan it works now. Its always these easy answers.